# Truncate a column of a csv file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, truncate

I'm new to Python and I have the following csv file (let's call it `out.csv`):

```
DATE,TIME,PRICE1,PRICE2
2017-01-15,05:44:27.363000+00:00,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,13:03:46.660000+00:00,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,21:25:07.320000+00:00,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,21:26:46.164000+00:00,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-16,12:40:11.593000+00:00,,1.0154
2017-01-16,12:40:11.593000+00:00,1.0004,
2017-01-16,12:43:34.696000+00:00,,1.0095
```

and I want to truncate the second column so the csv looks like:

```
DATE,TIME,PRICE1,PRICE2
2017-01-15,05:44:27,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,13:03:46,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,21:25:07,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,21:26:46,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-16,12:40:11,,1.0154
2017-01-16,12:40:11,1.0004,
2017-01-16,12:43:34,,1.0095
```

This is what I have so far..

```
with open('out.csv','r+b') as nL, open('outy_3.csv','w+b') as nL3:
  new_csv = []
  reader = csv.reader(nL)
  for row in reader:
      time = row[1].split('.')
      new_row = []
      new_row.append(row[0])
      new_row.append(time[0])
      new_row.append(row[2])
      new_row.append(row[3])
      print new_row
      nL3.writelines(new_row)
```

1. I can't seem to get a new line in after writing each line to the new csv file.
2. This definitely doesnt look or feel pythonic

Thanks

Comment: It seems you already tried some. Could you show me what you did?

Comment: So you want someone to write you _two_ pieces of code to show both pythonic and non-pythonic ways of doing it? Problem is there may be more than one of the former and are probably an infinite number of the latter... Probably the best way for you to learn something would be to try coding it yourself, and if you can't get it to work or think there might be a much better approach, _then_ start asking questions here.

Comment: @martineau is that better?

Comment: Yes, that's better, and now your question has been reopened.

Answer (score 0):

The missing newlines issue is because the `file.writelines()` method doesn't automatically add line separators to the elements of the argument it's passed, which it expects to be an sequence of strings. If these elements represent separate lines, then it's your responsibility to ensure each one ends in a newline.

However, your code is tries to use it to only output a single line of output. To  fix that you should use `file.write()` instead because it expects its argument to be a single string—and if you want that string to be a separate line in the file, it must end with a newline or have one manually added to it.

Below is code that does what you want. It works by changing one of the elements of the list of strings that the `csv.reader` returns **in-place**, and then writes the modified list to the output file as *single* string by `join()`ing them all back together, and then manually adds a newline the end of the result (stored in `new_row`).

```
import csv

with open('out.csv','rb') as nL, open('outy_3.csv','wt') as nL3:
    for row in csv.reader(nL):
        time_col = row[1]
        try:
            period_location = time_col.index('.')
            row[1] = time_col[:period_location]  # only keep characters in front of period
        except ValueError:  # no period character found
            pass  # leave row unchanged
        new_row = ','.join(row)
        print(new_row)
        nL3.write(new_row + '\n')
```

Printed (and file) output:

```
DATE,TIME,PRICE1,PRICE2
2017-01-15,05:44:27,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,13:03:46,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,21:25:07,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-15,21:26:46,0.9987,1.0113
2017-01-16,12:40:11,,1.0154
2017-01-16,12:40:11,1.0004,
2017-01-16,12:43:34,,1.0095
```